# Is there any way to delete these boot loader?

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

[image]

I want to re install ubuntu, but there are some complication trouble.
When I stick USB installer to my computer, Grub rescue always appearing.
Although I did like this,

```
bootrec.exe/fixmbr
bootrec.exe/fixboot
```

It doesn't work
Then I also format my Windows several times, but nothing has changed.
It was no use either that checking windows EFI partition, because that 3 things in the picture -manjaro, arch, ubuntu- was not found.

What should I do? Should I go to the A/S center? or Is there something another way?

Comment: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info  It looks like you have UEFI and are booting in UEFI. But then you always have to boot in UEFI boot mode, not any BIOS/Legacy boot.

Comment: Were you able to boot the Ubuntu installer and complete an installation, but it's not booting now? It looks like this is the case, based on the boot manager screen you've shown; but your description isn't clear on the matter. Please run the Boot Repair tool to get the BootInfo Summary, as oldfred has suggested; and please clarify exactly what you've done and what's not working.

Comment: I just implemented the boot-repair-disk and try to re-install my ubuntu with installer USB. but it shows only grub rescue. and After I install other linux OS and I enter to windows by grub of that linux, the grub in that one doesn't run anymore. then Is there any way of this case?